# Having problem with android permission: ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, android-permissions

I have a Firebase storage containing images, i have a Firebase document containing these images Urls, titles and the uploader's userId.

I want to display the user's images in a recycleview.

I did my recycler view, and my adapter, it seems fine to me.
So when the app wants to display it, it gives the no ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT permission "error".
As i see there is no specific permission like this. I have tried with the EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission but it gave the same error message.

Here is my Adapter and Display classes:

Adapter:

```
public class Tr_Receipt_Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Tr_Receipt_Adapter.ViewHolder>{
    private List<Tr_Receipt> Tr_Rec_List = new ArrayList<>();

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.tr_list_receipt, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Tr_Receipt receipt = Tr_Rec_List.get(position);

        holder.nameTextView.setText(receipt.getTr_rec_name());
        Uri imgUri = Uri.parse(receipt.getTr_rec_url());
        holder.imageView.setImageURI(imgUri);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return Tr_Rec_List.size();
    }

    public void addData(Tr_Receipt newData) {
        Tr_Rec_List.add(newData);
        notifyDataSetChanged(); // Notify RecyclerView about the data change
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView nameTextView;

        ImageView imageView;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            nameTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tr_receipt_name_et);
            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tr_receipt_imgv);
        }
    }
}
```

Display class:

```
public class Tr_Receipt_Retrieve extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String LOG_TAG = MainActivity.class.getName();

    private static final int READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_REQUEST = 100;

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private Tr_Receipt_Adapter adapter;

    FirebaseUser currentUser;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tr_receipt_retrieve);

        FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

        if (currentUser != null) {
            String userID = currentUser.getUid();
            // Use userID to load data specifically for this user from Firestore
            loadDataFromFirestore(userID);
        } else {
            // Handle the case where the user is not signed in
        }

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            // Permission is not granted, request it
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_REQUEST);
        } else {
            // Permission already granted, perform the action that requires this permission
            String userID = currentUser.getUid();
            loadDataFromFirestore(userID);
        }

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        adapter = new Tr_Receipt_Adapter(); // Create your adapter instance
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        if (requestCode == READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_REQUEST) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // Permission is granted, proceed with loading data or any other functionality
                String userID = currentUser.getUid();
                loadDataFromFirestore(userID);
            } else {
                // Permission denied, handle accordingly (e.g., show an explanation, disable functionality)
            }
        }
    }

    private void loadDataFromFirestore(String userID) {
        FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

        db.collection("tr_receipt")
                .whereEqualTo("userID", userID)
                .get()
                .addOnSuccessListener(queryDocumentSnapshots -> {
                    // Handle the retrieved data
                    for (DocumentSnapshot document : queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                        // Convert each document to your object model and add it to your adapter
                        Tr_Receipt object = document.toObject(Tr_Receipt.class);
                        Log.d("RetrievedObject", object.toString());
                        adapter.addData(object); // Method to add data to your adapter
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(e -> {
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Valami szar");
                    // Handle any errors while fetching data
                });
    }
}
```

Thank you for you answers!

Comment: "i have a Firebase document containing these images Urls, titles and the uploader's userId." -- where do you get the URLs from? Do they point to images on the Internet, such as on a Web server? Or, are they actually `Uri` values that (in theory) point to local images on the device?

Comment: they point to local images on the device

Comment: Then your problem lies there. You might want to update your [mcve] to show how exactly you are getting those image `Uri` values. You need to [take persistable `Uri` permissions](https://commonsware.com/blog/2020/08/08/uri-access-lifetime-still-shorter-than-you-might-think.html) to be able to safely save a `Uri`.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information CommonsWare asked for, and please also respond using @.